# Why is my php script not send the contact form to my email?

Tags: php, forms, server, contacts

I tried creating a simple PHP script to send an email to me when someone fills out a contact form on my website but I get nan error that says:

inspirehealth.today is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST('first_name');
$last_name = $_POST('last_name');
$email = $_POST('email');
$message = $_POST('message');

$to = "lewkowicz613@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message from Inspire Health";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name);
echo "Your Message Has Been Sent";

?>
```

and here is my html file relevant to the form

```
<section class="section-form js--contact" id="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Please Subscribe to Our Email List!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post" action="form_process.php" class="contact-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <label for="message">Drop us a line</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Im not sure why its not working properly. Is it a server thing because I uploaded all the files to my domain root directory.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you get a 500 check the server's error log.

Comment: **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string*** ... turn on error checking and display

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is a global array, so try:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "lewkowicz613@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message from Inspire Health";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name);
echo "Your Message Has Been Sent";

?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When I used your code the message was sent but no "From " or first name or last name or email was included

Comment: Glad to hear it sent.. I only copied your code and amended the $_POST lines. I suggest checking examples of mail() usage and debugging your script to find out why the from field isn't being populated :)